# csvsimple problem: csvreader reads > as?, what can I do?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, catcodes, csvsimple

I'm a beginner using LaTex. Currently I'm doing my thesis project and I need to do a table from a csv. However, csvreader from the csvsimple package is giving me problems because it reads > as ¿ and < as !. I have tried a lot of things and still can't solve it. The csv is the following:

```
Nombre,Frec,Prop
Quad > 75 cc,1,0.0001
Autocar,2,0.0002
Quad < 75 cc,7,0.0006
```

The table I get is the following:

[image]

My code is the following:

```
\begin{longtable}{lcc}
\caption{Tabla de frecuencias de TipoVehiculo}
\hline
\bfseries Tipo de Vehículo & \bfseries Frecuencia & \bfseries Proporción \\
\hline
\endhead
\csvreader[
    late after line= \\,
    late after last line=\\\hline,
    before reading={\catcode`\"=9}
]
{Tablas/TipoVehiculo.csv}
{Nombre=\Nombre,Frec=\Frec,Prop=\Prop}%
{\Nombre & \Frec & \Prop}
\end{longtable}
```

TipoVehiculo is the csv containing the data. I'm using longtable because my table is quite long. I have tried using catcodes, quotes but nothing have solved the issue. Any idea why is happening? Thank you

Comment: add `\usepackge[T1]{fontenc}` You should have this anyway to get correct hyphenation for non-english words.

Comment: It gives me the following error: ```undefined control sequence missing begin document```. Which is rare because I have \begin document.

Comment: the actual tex error in the log will show you which command is undefined (it is hard to see how adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` can lead to that error, but you provided no example). In any case that is necessary to get correct hyphenation and to have > typeset as >.

Comment: oh `\usepackage` of course not `\usepackge`

Comment: Thank you David for your help. I just solved it. Have a nice day :)